# Is there a way to count media files in twilio incoming messages through functions?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Is there a way to count media files in twilio incoming messages through functions?
What variable should I pass in? Or what property should I access all the media files and possibly count them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [webhook request for an incoming message](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/guides/webhook-request) contains all the information about the message. Particularly, it includes a `NumMedia` parameter that tells you how many media files there are in the incoming message.

When using Twilio Functions you can read this out of the `event` object.

```js
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  const numMedia = parseInt(event.NumMedia, 10);

  console.log(`This message has ${numMedia} image(s)`);

  callback(null, new Twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse());
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I found the property `NumMedia` to work for me (But not through the event argument) I achieved this through `context.getTwilioClient()` with the  `message()` function.  

Will the same `event` have`MediaUrl0` and `MediaUrl1` ? 
What argument should I pass for `event` in the Flow functions ?

Comment: Are you processing this through a Studio Flow?

Comment: Yes, I am using Studio Flow.

Comment: Then you need to pass the information from the flow to the function when you use the function widget. The information will be available from the trigger as `{{trigger.message.NumMedia}}`.

Comment: Ok, Thanks, good to know another approach on getting the attachment. I do however am looking for other properties like `MediaUrl0` and `MediaUrl1` depending on the number of media attached to an incoming message. (I know this is an extra information, I can post this as another question, if this is getting crowded)

Comment: They will also be available from the trigger. You can pass them all to your Function through the widget with the format `{{trigger.message.MediaUrlN}}` for each `N` from 0 to 9. If there is a parameter in the [Twilio webhook request parameters for SMS/MMS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/guides/webhook-request), then it will appear as a variable attached to the trigger in Studio.

Comment: Alright, Thanks! Even though its a lot of arguments, I do get the limitation of 10 attachments per message. Again thanks got a solution working.

Comment: I think the limitations come partially from the total size that carriers allow on the network. Hopefully this is something you can work around.